# How to add Bootstrap 4 without Tether?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting the below error after adding Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.5).

```
bootstrap.js:2676 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)(…)
```

I don't want to use the tooltips feature which requires tether.min.js for bootstrap therefore I don't want to add additional tether.min.js.

Is there anyway to use bootstrap 4 without adding tether.min.js ?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18732#issuecomment-168243561, you will have to exclude tooltip.js manually and possibly build a new minified version of bootstrap.js in order to get rid of this error without including tether.min.js.