# Can't make Tether work for Bootstrap 4 when bundling with Webpack

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-4, vue.js

I've spend two days trying to make Bootstrap to be bundled using Webpack. I've made jQuery work but in order for Bootstrap to be fully operational, we also need Tether to work (in my case - for popovers). I've followed [this guide](https://www.namekdev.net/2016/08/load-boostrap-4-alpha-into-vue-js-project/#comment-3069027256) and well as [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-loader#bootstrap-4-internal-dependency-solution). Still, the issue remains and I'm getting the error telling me that *popover is not a function*.

My config looks like this.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./index.js"],
  //entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./index.js", "tether"],
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: "bundle.js" },
  plugins: [new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    jquery: "jquery",
    "window.$": "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    "window.jquery": "jquery",
    "Tether": "tether",
    "window.Tether": "tether",
    // Popover: "exports?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
  })],
  ...
}
```

During the course of the last days, I've tried virtually anything and I'm out of ammo. How can I troubleshoot it further?

There are others with [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135593/how-to-require-tether-with-webpack) unresolved but also those who seem to [get Tether unwillingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585924/how-to-add-bootstrap-4-without-tether). I'm so confused at the moment that I could cry...

Comment: I didn't needed this config, You can see my example [here](https://github.com/mimani/vue-example/tree/popover-example) with webpack. I just imported it in [index.html](https://github.com/mimani/vue-example/blob/popover-example/index.html#L11) and it worked.

Comment: @saurabh I can't see anything about Tether (or Bootstrap, which in my case is the one requiring Tether) in the *package.json*. Are we talking about the same *popover()*?

Comment: I am talking about this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/

Comment: @saurabh Ah, sorry. It's me being insufficiently clear. I was already in the bed when I saw your message. Yes, as you say, the link from *index.html* to the source works - that's how I have it resolved at the moment. The problem I'm fighting with now is that I want to pack them all (*jquery.js*, *tether.js* and *bootstrap.js*) into a single *bundle.js* file. I was also intending to do that for all the CSS's but I'm thinking that Webpack perhaps isn't as great as everybody seems to sing about, hehe.

Comment: If you have time to take a whack at the **bundled** approach for Webpack, feel free to shoot. A buddy on my team mentioned that he's going to bounty this question +100 if it gets resolved properly and entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my working Bootstrap JS and SCSS in vueJS project:

In **webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery',
      Tether: 'tether', tether: 'tether'
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
};
```

In **main.js**

```
// Globally require jQuery, you cannot access jQuery from Console without this code
window.$ = require('jquery')

import 'bootstrap' // importing bootstrap.js
import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
import "./assets/scss/main.scss"

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

In **main.scss**

```
$font-family-primary: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; // Customize the bootstrap scss
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

My git setup https://github.com/syed-haroon/vue-js-2-basic-setup

I also encourage you to take look at this URL for more sophisticate work setup https://github.com/prograhammer/example-vue-project

Comment: Can you post a link to a Git with the contents?

Comment: @KonradViltersten just added it in git for you https://github.com/syed-haroon/vue-js-2-basic-setup I also encourage you to take look at this URL for more sophisticate work setup https://github.com/prograhammer/example-vue-project

Answer (score 1):

Using React, webpack and Bootstrap 4, it kept asking me "bootstrap tooltips require tether" even though I had added 'Tether': 'tether' to plugins.
So I had to add tether/dist/js/tether.min.js' under entry to make it work. see below

```
    module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script-loader!tether/dist/js/tether.min.js',
    'script-loader!bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx',
  ],
  externals: {
    jQuery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jQuery',
      'jQuery': 'jQuery',
      'Tether': 'tether'
    }),
```